# Who initiates SWIFT MT101, creditor or debtor?

Tags: swift

Who initiates SWIFT MT101 instruction?

Is it generated by creditor to take funds from debtor or generated by debtor to give funds to creditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SWIFT documentation](https://www2.swift.com/knowledgecentre/publications/us1m_20220722/2.0?topic=mt101-scope.htm) states that the initiator of the message should be the side to be debited.